# Download binary file with Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, filesaver.js

For example, downloading of PDF file:

```
axios.get('/file.pdf', {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/pdf'
      }
}).then(response => {
    const blob = new Blob([response.data], {
      type: 'application/pdf',
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'file.pdf');
});
```

The contend of downloaded file is:

```
[object Object]
```

What is wrong here? Why binary data not saving to file?

Comment: What is FileSaver defined as?

Comment: @zevee `import FileSaver from 'file-saver';` but this shouldn't be a problem. I've tried even `downloadjs` library, a result is the same

Comment: Probably, here's something related to babel compiler

Answer (score 133):

I was able to create a workable gist (without using FileSaver) as below:

```
axios.get("http://my-server:8080/reports/my-sample-report/",
        {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/pdf'
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf'); //or any other extension
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Thanks, `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` was what I missed.

Comment: `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` is the solution

Comment: This has also helped me serve Microsoft Office files, so your post is universally helpful!

Comment: OMG. You are absolute life saver. I knew this snippet will work even before i paste it.

Comment: Thank you so much,. its works but how can i pass data or request with data to the server?

Comment: How can we cancel the started download?

Comment: @Nayab Siddiqui-  could you please answer this question, Thanks ---    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065615/how-to-download-file-with-axios-in-node-js-and-write-to-the-response

Comment: how can  I display pdf in browser

Comment: working but the file size is in bytes. file is not downloading completely, it's currupted

Comment: Used this to download xlsx file sent as a streaming response from FastAPI. Many solutions on other questions are overly complicated and don't seem to work (anymore?), but this is simple and works perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

I was able to download a tgz file based on Nayab Siddiqui answer.

```
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;
const axios = require('axios'); 

await axios.get('http://myServer/myFile.tgz',
        {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer', // Important
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/gzip'
            }
        })
        .then(async response => {
            await fsPromises.writeFile(__dirname + '/myFile.tgz', response.data, { encoding: 'binary' });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log({ error });
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

This approach might be helpful to someone looking for answer in the future.

```
var axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");

var config = {
  method: "get",
  url: YOUR_REQUEST_URL,
  responseType: "arraybuffer",
  headers: {
   //put your headers here if any required
  },
};

axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    fs.writeFileSync("/path/to/file", Buffer.from(response.data));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score -3):

---

It looks like response.data is just a regular object.  Blobs take in their first argument "an Array of ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob, or DOMString objects."

Try wrapping it in JSON.stringify

```
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(response.data)]
```

Then it will satisfy the DOMString requirement.