# How can I download image in React?

Tags: reactjs, image, blob

I want to try to download an image by clicking on a button, but when I click on the button, it is not downloading the image, but it is directly opening the image. But I want to download the image, so how can I download the image in React?

```html
<a
  href="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-70238371,imgsize-89579,width-400,resizemode-4/70238371.jpg"
  download
>
  <i className="fa fa-download" />
</a>
```

Comment: The `download` attribute only works for same-origin URLs - you can't use it to download a file from another site.

Comment: so what is solution for download when different-origin URLs?

Comment: You can refer the URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65381723/download-image-from-cloudinary-url

Answer (score 23):

I came across this SO question trying to figure out how to download a PNG image and found that [Shubham Verma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57056741/how-can-i-download-image-in-react/57057809#57057809) didn't quite do it for me as the downloaded file couldn't be opened. I needed to use arraybuffer to convert the image.

Here's the code that worked.

```
function App() {
  const download = e => {
    console.log(e.target.href);
    fetch(e.target.href, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {}
    })
      .then(response => {
        response.arrayBuffer().then(function(buffer) {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer]));
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute("download", "image.png"); //or any other extension
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <a
        href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6b/Hello_Web_Series_%28Wordmark%29_Logo.png"
        download
        onClick={e => download(e)}
      >
        <i className="fa fa-download" />
        download
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-gould-h1l72

P.S.: The download approach was taken from the following answer, but I used plain fetch instead of Axios.
*[Download binary file with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040247/download-binary-file-with-axios/50220546#50220546)*

Comment: I'm using Chrome latest version (as of 16 Feb 2024) and this approach does no longer work (you can test in the codesandbox provided). It opens the image url in the same tab.

Answer (score 18):

Install file-saver package:

```
npm i file-saver
```

Your React component:

```
  import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'

  const Index = () => {
    const downloadImage = () => {
      saveAs('image_url', 'image.jpg') // Put your image URL here.
    }

    return <Button onClick={downloadImage}>Download!</Button>
  }
```

Comment: can we use this library to save images in phone gallery?

Comment: This opens the image in a new tab in Firefox, it doesn't download it.

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this:

```
function App() {
  const download = () => {
    var element = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob(
      [
        "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-70238371,imgsize-89579,width-400,resizemode-4/70238371.jpg"
      ],
      { type: "image/*" }
    );
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = "image.jpg";
    element.click();
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <a
        href="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-70238371,imgsize-89579,width-400,resizemode-4/70238371.jpg"
        download
        onClick={() => download()}
      >
        <i className="fa fa-download" />
        download
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a working URL: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-noether-3nu2p?fontsize=14

**Note**: More things can be done. I have just created this for demo purposes.

Comment: its download but image not able to open

Comment: It doesnt work anymore ..also checked on your provided link

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to download an image with a URL and dynamic name.

```
const download = async() => {
    const originalImage = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ninja-things-1/1772/ninja-simple-512.png";
    const image = await fetch(originalImage);

    // Split image name
    const nameSplit = originalImage.split("/");
    const  duplicateName = nameSplit.pop();

    const imageBlog = await image.blob()
    const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlog)
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = imageURL;
    link.download = "" + duplicateName + "";
    document.body.appendChild(link)
    link.click()
    document.body.removeChild(link)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) package helps us to save files on the client-side for web applications.

- **Installation:**

  ```
  npm i file-saver
  ```
- **Syntax:**

  ```
  FileSaver.saveAs("https://codemaker2015.github.io/image", "image.jpg");
  ```
- **Usage:**

  ```
  import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'

  const Main = () => {
      const downloadImage = () => {
          saveAs('image_url', 'image.jpg') // Put your image URL here.
      }

      return <Button onClick={downloadImage}>Download</Button>
  }
  ```

For more, see [its npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver).

Answer (score -1):

```
const Download = () => {
  const [downloadURL, setDownloadURL] = useState("");

  const download = async () => {
    const result = await fetch(fetchURLHere, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {},
    });
    const blob = await result.blob();
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    setDownloadURL(url);
  };

  const handleDownload = async (e) => {
    try {
      await download();
      // Call this method when you've finished using an object URL to let the browser know not to keep the reference to the file any longer.
      URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadURL);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleDownload} type="button" className="">
      <a href={downloadURL} download={setNameForFile}>
        Download Image
      </a>
    </button>
  );
};
```