# Download image from cloudinary url

Tags: reactjs, image, download, cloudinary

I have my react project where I edit images and generate a new one. Now I want to download the generated image. I am using cloudinary for that and I have the url of the image.

But the main problem is that I am unable to download the image. I tried

```
<a href="link" download> Download </a>
```

But it didn't work. It just opens the image but does not downloads it.

I want to only download the image, nothing more.

If you have any idea please do share

Live sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-mountain-lf4lk?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't need an external library to achieve that functionality. Just add the Cloudinary `flags` => `attachment` transformation (`fl_attachment` in URLs) and that will set the `Content-Disposition` header with value 'attachment' and the file will download.

```
<a href="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/fl_attachment/sample.jpg">Download</a>
```

You can optionally set a custom filename of the downloaded file by using the format `fl_attachment:my_custom_filename`.

```
<a href="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/fl_attachment:my_custom_filename/sample.jpg">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used js-file-download. Working sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-monad-pc6l9?file=/src/App.js:76-92

Answer (score 0):

Use cloudinary transformation URL adding attachment, this generate a new url to download your file directly.

For example:

```
//id is your public_id file in cloudinary
export const getImageAttachment = async (id) => {
return await cloudinary.url(id, {
    flags: "attachment:imgname"
})
```

This return a new URL, you can use to add in `<a/>` tag `href={}` for example, and download your file.

I hope I´ve helped.

More info:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformation_reference#fl_attachment