# download image from unsplash Api in js

Tags: javascript

I am using unsplash API to show images. I want to download the image when user click on download icon, but I don't know how to add this functionality. Here is what I did so far. In the below code I fetch the images from unsplash API and display them in `imageContainer` by using display grid:

Here is my html:

```
<!-- image container -->
<div class="imageContainer grid mt-10 p-2"></div>

<!-- image popup container -->
<div class="container height content z-20">
  <div class="icons">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down downloadIcon"></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark crossIcon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="imgShowed imgfit z-20"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my js:

```js
let imageContainer = document.querySelector(".imageContainer");
let imgShowed = document.querySelector(".imgShowed");
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let crossIcon = document.querySelector(".crossIcon");
let downloadIcon = document.querySelector(".downloadIcon")
// function to fetch image
function getimage() {
  imageContainer.innerHTML = "";
  (url =
    "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=" +
    input.value +
    "&per_page=1200&client_id=5OXcnxdQpZLtAG0_jRNpqEQhTlUOQL3TKviFAUbBKm8"),
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
    
        data.results.forEach((element) => {
          let Div = document.createElement("Div");
          Div.setAttribute("class", "imgDiv");
          Div.setAttribute("data-downloadurl", `${element.links.download}`);
          let img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = `${element.urls.regular}`;
          Div.appendChild(img);
          document.querySelector(".imageContainer").appendChild(Div);
          imagepopup()
        });
      });
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", getimage);

// image popup function
function imagepopup(){
  let imgDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".imgDiv");
  imgDiv.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
      container.style.display="block"
      let target = e.currentTarget
      let clickedimagesrc = target.firstChild.src
      imgShowed.innerHTML=`<img src="${clickedimagesrc}" class="imgfit" alt="...">`
      downloadIcon.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        let url=target.dataset.downloadurl
        downloadIMG(url)
      })
    })
  });
}

function downloadIMG(){
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.style.display = 'none';
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(url);
    link.download = file.name;
    link.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Vuejs, but you can adapt it to yours.
You will need to convert the download imageUrl to a blob and use the window.URL.createObjectURL method to get the url.

Use the generated URL in anchor tag and use the download attribute.

```
<a :href="imageDownloadUrl" :download="idModal">Download</a>


data() {
    return {
        imageDownloadUrl: "",
    };
},

methods: {
    async toDataURL(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const imageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // console.log(imageUrl);
        this.imageDownloadUrl = imageUrl;
    },

    getImageUrl(id) {
        const url = this.$store.state.baseURL;
        const key = this.$store.state.apiKey;
        const ixid =
            "MnwxMTc4ODl8MHwxfHNlYXJjaHwxfHxwdXBweXxlbnwwfHx8fDE2MTc3NTA2MTM";

        const endpoint = `${url}/photos/${id}/download?ixid=${ixid}&client_id=${key}`;

        // the endpoint it's like: https://api.unsplash.com/photos/imageId/download?ixid=ixId&client_id=apiKey
        
        // the full path can be found in **links.download_location** of the returned array of images, also get your **ixid** from the link and make sure to include apiKey.

        axios
            .get(endpoint)
            .then((response) => {
                let url = response.data.url;
                this.toDataURL(url);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
},
```

NOTE: If you're using the example from the link below, try not to **return window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)** as you'll have a promise, but since you only need the **url** simply save it to a variable and use it as the **href** value for the anchor tag with a download attribute (as above)...the download attribute value is optional.

Helpful links:

Vanilla js implementation: [How can I create a button which Fetches image from API and download to the local with using ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978538/how-can-i-create-a-button-which-fetches-image-from-api-and-download-to-the-local)

Download file with anchor tag: [How to make PDF file downloadable in HTML link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link/64910792#64910792)

createObjectURL explained: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: I am looking into your issue but as I found here its saying chrome as a deprecated cross-origin URL to download https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click

Comment: if you see the second answer may be that can help you

Comment: If you mean the answer with a downloadImage function... Then that should work. Same as above though... 

In @nidhi-sharma code, within the forEach loop, you can get each 'element.links.download_location' saved to a variable, say: downLoadUrl, and pass it as an argument in the function toDataUrl above, to get the URL used in <a> tag for download...

Answer (score 0):

Short implementation of download Image using anchor tag with reference.

```
<a download="img" target="_blank" class="hidden" ref="imageDownloadRef"></a>

async downloadImage(img: any) {
  const imgUrl = `${img.links.download_location}&client_id=${API_KEY}`
  const response = await fetch(imgUrl)
  const blob = await response.blob()
  this.$refs['imageDownloadRef'].href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  const imageDownloadLink = this.$refs.imageDownloadRef
  imageDownloadLink.click()
}
```

P.S- https://help.unsplash.com/en/articles/2511258-guideline-triggering-a-download