# print and download image in React js

Tags: reactjs

I have code like this :

```js
<ImageGrid>

<MyCard title="first image" url="https://test.test" image="https://img1.link"  ''Button here' />

</ImageGrid>
```

```html
const MyCard = props => {
  return (
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={props.url}>
      <div
        <BasicImage alt={props.title} src={props.image} />
        <p>{props.title}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  )
}

export default MyCard
```

I want to add button in MyCard to print img1 and button to download img1
thank you

Comment: Can you please add the code of MyCard component also?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onClick` event to handle a function that can use to download and print the image.

```
<ImageGrid>

<MyCard title="first image" url="https://test.test" image="https://img1.link"  onClick={() => { this.downloadAndPrint(); }} />

</ImageGrid>
```

If you use class component then bind the function like this:

```
this.downloadAndPrint= this.downloadAndPrint.bind(this);
```

Function:

```
downloadAndPrint() {
  //function
}
```

For download take a look on this similar issue:
[How to download image in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57056741/how-to-download-image-in-reactjs)

And to print the image you can use library like this:
[react-to-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print)