# Download image from a third-party server button

Tags: javascript, html

In any browser, if you saw an image, you can right-click on it and click "save as" to download it.

I'm trying to make a button to download an image

[image]

The download button should download the image above, the barcode.

I am using react, not sure if this has something to do with the answers.

I read that you can use the `<a/>` tag with the `download` attribute, however, I'm on Firefox, and it's redirecting me to a page where the barcode image is hosted, and it's not opening the download window instead:

[image]

The code is pretty simple, it look as follows:

```html
<a href='https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=${product.barcode}&code=&multiplebarcodes=true&backcolor=%23ffffff&quietzone=10&quietunit=Px&size=Small' download>click me</a>
```

From the MDN docs:

> download only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data:
> schemes.

I want to implement this, how can I do it?
I'm not the owner of the server where the image is hosted.

Can we do that in 2023?

The other questions are mixing between local images and images hosted on other servers.
So I thought I could create this thread for people interested only in images on third party servers. - so we are all front-end here, no back-end related stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)

Comment: @0stone0, no because the other question refers to local images on the server, in my question I'm referring to images on remote servers, which I may have no access to

Comment: Then your actual question is how to fix CORS. There are tons of question on that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57056741/how-to-download-image-in-reactjs

Comment: @0stone0, why do I have to cross all that CORS dark way as a programmer, while the user can simply right-click on an image and save it peacefully, it's not fair, so there must be a soltuion

Answer (score 1):

I think your question refers to this old question.

You need something on the server to send a Content-Disposition header to set the file as an attachment so the browser will not try to handle the file internally.

Please see:
[href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)

Comment: great, **from the MDN docs**  _"download only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes."_. OK, what's the solution then?

Comment: you need to make sure that it is one of those: _same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes_

Answer (score 0):

It only works on the same website, not an external link. Try an image of the same website. Ex: `<a href="images/detailed-product.png" download>click</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [proxy](https://httptoolkit.com/blog/cors-proxies/#:%7E:text=How%20do%20CORS%20proxies%20work%3F,target%20URL%20as%20a%20path) the request to avoid CORS issues. As the article states it's better to deploy your own proxy, but you can test with a free one, eg: https://codetabs.com/cors-proxy/cors-proxy.html

[StackBlitz updated example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hvqide?file=index.js,index.html):

```js
const downloadButton = document.querySelector('button');

downloadButton.onclick = () => {
  console.log('download button clicked');
  downloadImage(
    'https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=${product.barcode}&code=&multiplebarcodes=true&backcolor=%23ffffff&quietzone=10&quietunit=Px&size=Small'
  );
};

async function downloadImage(imageSrc) {
  try {
    const image = await fetch(imageSrc);
    const imageBlob = await image.blob();
    const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = imageURL;
    link.download = 'image.jpg';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Download image</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

To do that, you can utilize the `createObjectURL` static method from `URL` to create download link for the image. Then, we create temporary `<a>` in a variable to open that link programmatically.

```
async function downloadImage(imageSrc) {
  const image = await fetch(imageSrc)
  const imageBlob = await image.blob()
  const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob)

  const link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = imageURL
  link.download = 'myimage.jpg'
  document.body.appendChild(link)
  link.click()
  document.body.removeChild(link)
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work, it's saying there's an error https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fb3whw?file=index.js

Comment: It is not working because the request is blocked by the browser cors policy, try to add this code to your codebase and request from your origin aka from your client code domain. If your URL is added in the cors config by the server, it will work.