# Saving binary file in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm getting binary file from a remote server, but I am unable to correctly store it locally using the file system. When I try to open the saved file, it shows as incorrect format etc and doesn't open the file.
However, If I download the file directly from the site, it works fine. Need help on this. Thanks!

```
const fileData = await axios({ //this returns binary data.
    method: "get",
    url: instanceURL,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
    },
  });
  fs.writeFileSync(storePath, Buffer.from(fileData.data, "binary"));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download binary file with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040247/download-binary-file-with-axios)

Comment: I tried `fs.writeFileSync(storePath, new Blob([fileData.data]));` but that's giving `Blob not defined` error

Comment: I ended up using the `fs.createWriteStream` to write the data.